# MYSQL - Generate string in column 5 with data in columns 1, 2, 3 and 4 - Same Table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to understand how to populate column "Summary' with data from columns; Bedrooms, Bathrooms, Prop_type and Location with some additional text in between some of the data

Example:

```
Bedrooms = 3
Bathrooms = 2
Prop_type = Apartment
Location = Madrid
```

The result I would like to achieve in the column 5 would be;

"Apartment in Madrid with 3 Bedrooms & 2 Bathrooms, Madrid 3 Bed Apartment, 3 Bed & 2 Bathrooms in Marid"

I trust I have (this time) presented my question in an easy to understand format, if I have not I apologise in advance

Comment: Do you want a view (automatically updated) or a one-off UPDATE command? Is there a reason you have to do this inside the database and not in your application code?

Comment: Hi Emil, I would like this to dynamically update, although changes to the data are rare they do occur from time to time so a constant updating field is preferred.

Comment: Apologies the return key posted my last message... I would prefer the data to be kept in the table as it offers a convenient way to search the table and keep the workload to a min